# Create separate animation tracks for multiple animations?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have a binary animation data I successfully parsed to `bone:state`. Here is pseudocode how I currently create animation:

```py
context.scene.frame_start = 1
context.scene.frame_end = frameCount
#deselect any selected bones, if any selected
for frame in range(1, frameCount + 1):
    wm.progress_update(frame - 1)
    context.scene.frame_current = frame
    for name in boneNames:
        # do require operation with bones, fetch matching from armature
        # update matrix and parents, etc so on
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='Rotation', confirm_success=False)
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='Location', confirm_success=False)
    # deselect bone

# end, we now have animation in playback, yey...
```

The issue with this method that if I want to import another animation it would append existing.
What options do I have to manage multiple animations properly?

Comment: is not clear what do you want.   
do you want add a new animation after the original ones? or do you want remplace the original ones with a new one... ? or what?

Comment: I basically want to separate current animation I have on timeline from frame 0 to X into its own "whatever_blender_calls_it". Normal people call it 'tracks' but Blender is special so whatever it is the alternative in blender - I want to use that. NLA tracks?

Comment: actually blender have the NLA tracks. and you can access that usign object.animation_data.nla_tracks   and you can add or remove that

Comment: Got any specifics?